# Excel: Filter a sheet from value in another sheet

Tags: excel

Been trying a bunch of things but haven't come across an easy solution to this.

I have a sheet, Sheet A, which has, among others, a column called "City". I would like to be able to filter Sheet A along this City column. However, I want to be able to filter Sheet A based off the value of a cell in Sheet B. Essentially, I would like to be able to replicate the filter button in Sheet A City column and put it in Sheet B and be able to toggle the filter in Sheet B. I do not want to extract the data from Sheet A; I want Sheet A to be filtered.

**Sheet A**

```
City
Jamestown
Cape-Town
Hong Kong
Hong Kong
```

**Sheet B**

```
Hong Kong
```

Results in:

**Sheet A**

```
City
Hong Kong
Hong Kong
```

Comment: If you clear the filter control cell in **Sheet B**, do you want the filter opened-up, *(show_all)* in **Sheet A** ??

Comment: Yes. I want the filter control cell in Sheet B to act as the filter control would in Sheet A (or as closely as possible). If I could simply copy the filter control in Sheet A and put it in Sheet B, that would be perfect, but I don't think that is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code in the ThisWorkBook tab in VBA:

```
Private Sub workbook_Sheetchange(ByVal ws As Object, ByVal target As Range)
    If target.Address = "$A$2" And ws.Name = "Sheet7" Then
        Sheets("Sheet6").Range("A2:A6").AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=Sheets("Sheet7").Range("A2"), VisibleDropDown:=True
    End If

    If Sheets("Sheet7").Range("A2") = "" Then
        Sheets("Sheet6").ShowAllData
    End If
End Sub
```

[[image]

[[image]

[[image]

[[image]

Comment: I'm not well experienced with VBA. I put in the code in ThisWorkBook tab in VBA as pictured. Then what do I do after?

Comment: Edit: remember to accept as right answer please :-p

Comment: Can you tell me how to add the option to "release" the filter (select all)?

Comment: see edits above, added         If Sheets("Sheet7").Range("A2") = "" Then
            Sheets("Sheet6").ShowAllData
        End If